# Storing individual numbers of an int in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion

I was trying to write a program in which I take an input number,
example 891 and input each of these number in an array for example
`x[0] = 8`, `x[1] = 9` and `x[2] = 1`

I was trying to use recursion to implement my method:

```
void calc(int val, int k)
{
    static int number = val;
    if((val/10))
    {
        calc(val/10, k--);
    }
    int x = number - val*pow(10, k);
    cout << x << ", k = " << k << " and number = " << number << endl;
}

int main()
{
    //write a program that converts a number to string
    int number;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    number = 891;
    int k = 0;

    //while(number/10 != 0)
        k = 2;

    calc(number, k);
}
```

Basically I'm trying to use my recursive function to try to break the
number down in its finer parts, however I get an output of (in `val`):
91, 1, -8019. Is there a way I can improve on this, but maintaining
the structure?

Comment: Where's your array? Why `cin >> number;
   number = 891;`? Why `int k = 0;
        k = 2;`? Why `static int number = val;`?

Comment: Recursion will certainly work but it isn't necessary for this problem. It would use fewer computer resources to just use a loop. What do you mean by "improve"? It helps to define your goal.

Comment: My suspicion about 'k' is that it provides an index into the array to store the digits, and the OP was trying to use it to do modulo in a long hand way (pow function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void calc(int val)
{
    cout << "digit:"<<val % 10<< " and number = " << val << endl;
    if((val/10))
    {
        calc(val/10);
    }
}
```

This will print out each digit (which looks like what you are trying to do in the function).

Answer (score 2):

Both putting your data into an array and solving this problem recursively requires a bit of pointer arithmetic.
You'll need to allocate your array ahead of time, which means you need to know the number of digits. You'll also need to pass around the pointer to the array so that recursive calls can assign to it.
Below is a shortish solution that fits both of these requirements.

```
#import <math.h>
#import <iostream>
using namespace std;

void calc(int num, int* digs) {
  if (num > 0) {
    calc(num/10, digs-1); //recursive call, doing head recursion
    *digs = num %10; //assigning this digit
  }
}

int main() {
  //Get number from user
  int inputNumber;
  cout << "Input a number: ";
  cin >> inputNumber;

  int numDigits = log10(inputNumber) + 1;
  int outputArray[numDigits];

  //I give a pointer to the end of the array
  //This is because we are receiving digits from the end
  //So we traverse backwards from the end of the array
  calc(inputNumber, outputArray+numDigits-1);

  //Following is not logic, just printing
  for (int i=0; i < numDigits; i++) {
    cout << outputArray[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```